# Java Android cannot revoke symbol

Tags: java, android

I am currently going through a tutorial and I am struggling with this line:

```
Call<AccessToken>
```

`<AccessToken>` is marked red and my idea tells me

> cannot revoke symbol

, what does that mean is AccessToken just a placeholder?

```
public interface APIClient {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/oauth/token")
    Call<AccessToken> getNewAccessToken(
            @Field("code") String code,
            @Field("client_id") String clientId,
            @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
            @Field("redirect_uri") String redirectUri,
            @Field("grant_type") String grantType);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/oauth/token")
    Call<AccessToken> getRefreshAccessToken(
            @Field("refresh_token") String refreshToken,
            @Field("client_id") String clientId,
            @Field("client_secret") String clientSecret,
            @Field("redirect_uri") String redirectUri,
            @Field("grant_type") String grantType);

}
```

Comment: There should be a class called `AccessToken` somewhere. Either it is your class or you need to import a library. Maybe you can post a link to the tutorial you're using?

Comment: @sudo So it call the class AccessToken with the method getNew...

Comment: `getNew...` methods **return** an **object** of generic class `Call` with type parameter `AccessToken`.